# Merge 2 arrays: don't change indexes and add the 2nd values in order in the gaps

Tags: php, indexing, array-merge

I have two arrays. I want that I do not change the indexes of the first one and that the second one, is added by order in the gaps of the missing indexes:

```
$a = array(
     0 => 9,
     2 => 13
     );

$b = array(
     1 => 10,
     2 => 11,
     3 => 12,
     4 => 1
     );
```

I want this result:

```
$ab = array(
      0 => 9, 
      1 => 10, 
      2 => 13, 
      3 => 11, 
      4 => 12, 
      5 => 1
      );
```

I tried this:

```
$ab = $a+$b;    // Keeps indexes, but removes key 2 from array $ b
$ab = array_merge($a, $b);  // Change indexes
$ab = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b));     // Change indexes
$ab = array_merge($a, array_diff($b, $a));  // Change indexes
```

Comment: No, it´s not possible, I have simplified the example but $b has a minimum of five values and $a 0 to 5 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through `$b`, copying the elements to `$a`. But if the index already exists, increment an adjustment to get the new index.

```
function mergeArrays($a, $b) {
    $adjust = 0;
    foreach ($b as $i => $val) {
        while (isset($a[$i + $adjust])) {
            $adjust++;
        }
        $a[$i + $adjust] = $val;
    }
    ksort($a); // Put in order by new indexes
    return $a;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/633y3P)

Comment: Thanks Barmar! This work perfectly. Later I realized that I had to loop and add values one by one just like you and Georaldc said below.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like a straightforward merge. You can probably try running a loop through your second array and slowly adding elements to the first array in places where they fit

```
function mergeArrays($a, $b)
{
    foreach ($b as $i => $v) {
        while (array_key_exists($i, $a)) {
            $i++;
        }
        $a[$i] = $v;
    }

    ksort($a);

    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($a as $k => $v ) {
  $new_array[$k] = $v ;
}

foreach ($b as $k => $v ) {
  $new_array[$k] = $v ;
}

echo print_r(new_array);
```

Hope will help

Comment: I don't think this will work. Item 2 of b will overwrite a's item 2. And the rest of b will have wrong key number.

Comment: @andreas, this approach is good because you can extend it at wish. Example : you can do sum/average/whatever on  values with same key..

Comment: isn't that kind of obvious? You can extend any code with any code you like. Either way, IT WILL NOT work for the intended use OP wants. Try it and you will see.

Comment: I see this:  Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [2] => 11
    [1] => 10
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 1
) which is almost the same.

Comment: Almost the same? It doesn't even have all the values. Just give up. It's incorrect, there is nothing that can soften the edges here.

Comment: Your array is not properly sorted, missing the "13", has 5 items instead of requested 6, and has incorrect key numbers on most of the values. All the above listed is things that is wrong with your answer, it's not "almost the same". Give it up, or edit your answer to something that does create a correct array.

Comment: I'm not making the work for you  I'm giving the approach,  @Andreas.  Use your knowledge to use at wish id you like it or ignore my answer. Downvoting is a battle I leave to you

Comment: It definitely is not going to work but the approach at least does not produce a O(n*2) algorithm if you used destructuring assignment between 2 arrays.

Comment: @JasonTumusiime I agree with you it won't work, expecially with index 2. At the time of my very answer, I believe the double index "2" was not there (or maybe I didn't noticed it)

Comment: @Augusto I actually used your approach in trying to merge 2 very large arrays. I don't prefer state and variables in most data manipulation programs (IMO) but it worked. for me in my time of need, your approach was really helpful.